# Scrapy Request: TypeError(f'Request url must be str or unicode, got {type(url).__name__}'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to create my first spider **scraper** using scrapy to retrieve Instagram posts(captions, url images and videos). I get an error message: TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType But when debugging, I used the right url format and that its did pass though the get_url function. I'm not sure of what is causing the issue.

```
import scrapy
from urllib.parse import urlencode
import json
from datetime import datetime
API = 'api-key'
import logging
user_accounts = ["cream34246", "styledgood"]


def get_url(url):
    payload = {'api_key': API, 'proxy': 'residential', 'timeout': '20000', 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'https://api.webscraping.ai/html?' + urlencode(payload)
    return 
           
class InstagramSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'instagram'
    allowed_domains = ['api.scraperapi.com']
    custom_settings = {'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 5} 
    

    def start_requests(self):
        for username in user_accounts:
            url = f'https://www.instagram.com/{username}/?hl=en'
            yield scrapy.Request(get_url(url), callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        x = response.xpath("//script[starts-with(.,'window._sharedData')]/text()").extract_first()
        json_string = "{" + x.strip().split('= {')[1][:-1]
        data = json.loads(json_string)
        # all that we have to do here is to parse the JSON we have
        user_id = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['id']
        user = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['full_name']
        next_page_bool = \
            data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['page_info'][
                'has_next_page']
        edges = data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['edges']
        for i in edges:
            url = 'https://www.instagram.com/p/' + i['node']['shortcode']
            video = i['node']['is_video']
            date_posted_timestamp = i['node']['taken_at_timestamp']
            date_posted_human = datetime.fromtimestamp(date_posted_timestamp).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
            like_count = i['node']['edge_media_preview_like']['count'] if "edge_media_preview_like" in i['node'].keys() else ''
            comment_count = i['node']['edge_media_to_comment']['count'] if 'edge_media_to_comment' in i[
                'node'].keys() else ''
            captions = ""
            if i['node']['edge_media_to_caption']:
                for i2 in i['node']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges']:
                    captions += i2['node']['text'] + "\n"

            if video:
                image_url = i['node']['display_url']
            else:
                image_url = i['node']['thumbnail_resources'][-1]['src']
            item = {'username':user,'postURL': url, 'isVideo': video, 'date_posted': date_posted_human,
                    'timestamp': date_posted_timestamp, 'likeCount': like_count, 'commentCount': comment_count, 'image_url': image_url,
                    'captions': captions[:-1]}
            if video:
                yield scrapy.Request(get_url(url), callback=self.get_video, meta={'item': item})
            else:
                item['videoURL'] = ''
                yield item
        if next_page_bool:
            cursor = \
                data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['page_info'][
                    'end_cursor']
            di = {'id': user_id, 'first': 12, 'after': cursor}
            print(di)
            params = {'query_hash':'e769aa130647d2354c40ea6a439bfc08' , 'variables': json.dumps(di)}
            url = 'https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?' + urlencode(params)
            yield scrapy.Request(get_url(url), callback=self.parse_pages, meta={'pages_di': di})
```

The Logs and error:

```
2021-04-24 10:45:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2021-04-24 10:45:27 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2021-04-24 10:45:27 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2021-04-24 10:45:27 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\name\anaconda3\envs\envi\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 129, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\instascraper\instascraper\spiders\temp.py", line 35, in start_requests
    yield scrapy.Request(get_url(url), callback=self.parse)
  File "c:\users\name\anaconda3\envs\envi\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "c:\users\name\anaconda3\envs\envi\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 63, in _set_url
    raise TypeError(f'Request url must be str or unicode, got {type(url).__name__}')
TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType
2021-04-24 10:45:27 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your function that generates URLs doesn't return anything.

```
def get_url(url):
    payload = {'api_key': API, 'proxy': 'residential', 'timeout': '20000', 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'https://api.webscraping.ai/html?' + urlencode(payload)
    return
```

It returns `None` every time, instead of `proxy_url`. You need to fix it by having it `return proxy_url`.